# Real-valued analytic function (complex)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity, analytic-functions

I am studying elementary complex variable topic. An exercise in Brown-Churchill book asks us to show that if $f$ is analytic in a domain $D$ and real-valued at all points then $f$ must be constant throughout $D$.

This should be doable by following the proof of showing zero derivative implies constant. However, can I use the fact (which is already proved in the book): *If a function and its conjugate are both analytic in $D$, then $f$ is constant there.* ???

I am thinking that since in the exercise, $f$ and its conjugate are equal because $f$ is real-valued, then they are both analytic as $f$ is, and the conclusion follows. Is this all right?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: Your approach is correct

Answer (score 2):

Here is an application of Cauchy Riemann equations.

Suppose $f = u + iv$ be real valued , analytic function then $v = 0$. So by Cauchy Riemann equation we must have $u_x = u_y = 0$ implying that $u$ is a constant and consequently $f$ is constant.

Comment: Can you please guide me why this does not hold if we take $f(z)=e^{z}$?

Comment: @Kashif The exponential function need not be a real valued in a domain.

Comment: Apologies for writing my incomplete sentence, I meant to ask for $e^{z}$ on the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$ so in this domain, it assumes only real values right? Please clarify on this question.

Comment: The interval $(-\infty, \infty)$ is not an open set in $\mathbb{C}$, so it is not a domain.

Comment: This was a blunder I was ignorant about, thanks for the clarification. This helped.